# Принудительный выход устройства Android из режима блокировки

Tags: android, java, service

Написал службу (**Service**) для устройств с ОС **Android**. Работает прекрасно, но только в режиме, когда с телефоном работают (т.е. разблокирован и не в режиме сна). По блокировке телефона, служба перестает исполнять свои функции.

Вопрос следующий.

1. Что происходит со службой, по переходу устройства в режим сна?
2. Как организовать работу службы и в таком случае?
3. Можно ли по какому-то намерению (**Intent**), ассоциированному с неким событием на телефоне, принудительно вывести телефон из режима сна? Ведь, при том же входящем звонке, устройство переходит в активный режим.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что если служба постоянно работает, то активно кушается батарея и это очень сильно раздражает пользователя. Да и понятно почему.

Answer (score 3):

В общем для того, чтобы устройство не засыпало надо контролировать т.н. `WakeLock` - то есть если вы будете держать `WakeLock`, то `Service` не остановится, иначе он заснет вместе с устройством.

Паттерн использования может выглядеть так:

- Спим
- Некое событие (например `AlarmManager`)
- Захват (acquire) `WakeLock`
- Выполнение некой функции - например получени GPS координат, проверка Email да мало ли что еще!
- Отпускаем `WakeLock`
- Засыпаем

В общем как-то так
Не забудьте, что для использования WakeLock нужен специальный пермишен в манифесте: `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK`

Comment: Что ж, спасибо за ответ. Но как я понимаю, 3-й вопрос он не решает. Ведь не держать же мне из-за службы телефон все время в активном режиме (к сожалению ваш шаблон мне не подходит из-за специфики работы службы). Нет ли возможности зарегистрировать какой-то Приемник Широковещательных Намерений (BroadcastReceiver), который будет работать вне зависимости, спит телефон или нет и следить за некими системными событиями устройства. Заранее спасибо.